# How do I use XPPAUT?

Tags: 14.04

while I run the command **xpp linear2d.ode** the following window appears. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

1.2  Running the program

Run `XPPAUT` by typing `xpp linear2d.ode`. Replace `xpp` with whatever you have decided to call the executable with all the desired command line options. (
If you are using `winpp`, click on the `winpp` icon; then choose the file from the  file selection dialog box.) **Six windows will appear on the screen or they may be iconified** (depending on the command line options.) (If any of the windows appear “dead” or blank, iconify them manually and then uniconify them. Next time run `XPPAUT` without the `-iconify` command line option.

2 possible options I see ...

- You are missing command line options; in this case a printer choice.
- `xpp` could contain a command to open the printer dialog.

Comment: I use **UBuntu 14.04 LTS** OS .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the binary of the XPPAUT program in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS packaging is called 'xppaut' not 'xpp'. What you see when you run `xpp` is the X Printing Panel which is absolutely not you are looking for. The manual you've been reading is probably written for a previous version of the program where the default Makefile used for compiling has a directive for producing a binary named 'xpp', and that's why writer suggested you might need to replace xpp with the executable named in your system. In the latest versions of xppaut, the Makefile produces xppaut by default and Ubuntu 14.04 packaging also follows that. See [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/xppaut/filelist) for the location of the xppaut binary in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (hint: it's `/usr/bin/xppaut`).

Thus, you need to type:

```
xppaut linear2d.ode
```